# Add a comma after certain digits in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have a column (F) full of 11 digit numbers, what I need is to split them like the following: 12,345,6789,00

I have the following formula which adds a comma after the first two digits however I don't know how to get it to add them in after the next 3 then 4.

```
=LEFT(F2,2)&","&MID(F2,3,LEN(F2))
```

The above formula outputs like this: 12,345678900

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `MID` all the way:

```
=MID(F2,1,2)&","&MID(F2,3,3)&","&MID(F2,6,4)&","&MID(F2,10,2)
```

Answer (score 6):

Have you considered using the `TEXT` function? This is simple and would do the trick:

```
=TEXT(F2,"00"",""000"",""0000"",""00")
```

Comment: I like your solution! Haven't thought of that version before.

Answer (score 2):

```
=left(F2,2)&","&mid(F2,3,3)&","&mid(F2,6,4)&","&right(F2,2)
```

Will give you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

=LEFT(F2,2) &","&MID(F2,3,3)&","&MID(F2,6,4)&","&RIGHT(F2,2)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Text to Columns function in the Data Tab of Excel. It will allow you to split the numbers based on number of digits. For this to work though, it needs to be the case that the number ALWAYS has 11 digits... otherwise some numbers will get cut in the wrong spot.

You can then Concotenate them back together with Commas inbetween.